# I left the channel, but my id remained in the list of subscribers. What's the matter? (laravel echo)

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I left the channel, after that I check the list of subscribers by [laravel-echo http-api](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#http-api), but I remained in the list of subscribed to the channel.

> What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I renamed channel name everywhere, cleared cache, restart queue and echo-server, but each time echo tried to subscribe to the old channel. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

**Found a reason ;). The page with connection has been opened on another computer.**